# How to solve Authentication error?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Error Code:

> {"documentation":"https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/400","errorcode":0,"message":"Bad
>   Request"}

I am going to get the access token from Salesforce account for that created one connected app from there i used Client_id and Client_Secret code for getting Access Token is it correct procedure to follow getting access token using AMPScript in Exacttarget?

I used this code

```
%%[
VAR @httppost, @apiid, @apistatusCode, @apiresponse, @apitoken
SET @apiid = '{"clientId": "clientId","clientSecret": "clientSecret"}'
SET @httppost = HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken","application/json",@apiid, false, @apistatusCode, @apiresponse)
]%%
%%=v(@httppost)=%%
```

Is this the correct procedure? Why this error coming? How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable naming is confusing.

Here's a `requestToken` example I've seen out-and-about:

```
%%[ 

var @auth, @url, @return_code, @response_data, @regex, @accessToken
set @auth = '{"clientId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","clientSecret":"YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"}'
set @url = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken"
set @return_code = httppost(@url,"application/json", @auth, @response_data)

IF @return_code == 200 THEN
  set @regex = '^{"accessToken":"(.*)",.*$'
  set @accessToken = regexmatch(@response_data, @regex, 1)
  /* AMPScript for the final REST API call here */
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: This is the same user group I am referring to. They have asked this question more than once under different user names

Comment: Thank You for Responding.. Even i am getting error.. My dought is in code clientId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","clientSecret":"YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" Instead of XXXXXXXXXXXXX, YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY we need to give salesforce connected app cientid and client secret right?

Comment: I need to get access token from salesforce so i used connected app client id and client secret getting authentication error how to solve this error

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm

Comment: That regex didn't work for me, so I updated it to SET @regex = '^{"access_token":"(.*?)"' just in case anyone else has issues.

Comment: Yeah the regex pattern needed updated for OAuth2.

Comment: Ah makes sense Adam. I should note that my update is slightly different I'm using access_token instead of accessToken because mine is for Salesforce API, NOT Marketing Cloud